# Getting No Output from my Powershell Functions

Tags: powershell

Sorry if you have seen this code but I did make some tweaks after I accepted the answer and got some interesting results and wasn't able to reopen previous thread for continuance.

My powershell seems to be running but the function calls are producing no result after `$filestore` in function execute.  What is going on? Are my functions not reading the inputs due to lack of global variables?

```
$filestore = Import-Excel 'C:\594 Sample of Filestore.xlsx'
function Import-Excel
{
  param (
    [string]$FileName,
    [string]$WorksheetName,
    [bool]$DisplayProgress = $true
  )

  if ($FileName -eq "") {
    throw "Please provide path to the Excel file"
    Exit
  }

  if (-not (Test-Path $FileName)) {
    throw "Path '$FileName' does not exist."
    exit
  }

  $FileName = Resolve-Path $FileName
  $excel = New-Object -com "Excel.Application"
  $excel.Visible = $false
  $workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($FileName)

  if (-not $WorksheetName) {
    Write-Warning "Defaulting to the first worksheet in workbook."
    $sheet = $workbook.ActiveSheet
  } else {
    $sheet = $workbook.Sheets.Item($WorksheetName)
  }

  if (-not $sheet)
  {
    throw "Unable to open worksheet $WorksheetName"
    exit
  }

  $sheetName = $sheet.Name
  $columns = $sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
  $lines = $sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

  Write-Warning "Worksheet $sheetName contains $columns columns and $lines lines of data"

  $fields = @()

  for ($column = 1; $column -le $columns; $column ++) {
    $fieldName = $sheet.Cells.Item.Invoke(1, $column).Value2
    if ($fieldName -eq $null) {
      $fieldName = "Column" + $column.ToString()
    }
    $fields += $fieldName
  }

  $line = 2


  for ($line = 2; $line -le $lines; $line ++) {
    $values = New-Object object[] $columns
    for ($column = 1; $column -le $columns; $column++) {
      $values[$column - 1] = $sheet.Cells.Item.Invoke($line, $column).Value2
    }  

    $row = New-Object psobject
    $fields | foreach-object -begin {$i = 0} -process {
      $row | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name $fields[$i] -Value $values[$i]; $i++
    }
    $row
    $percents = [math]::round((($line/$lines) * 100), 0)
    if ($DisplayProgress) {
      Write-Progress -Activity:"Importing from Excel file $FileName" -Status:"Imported $line of total $lines lines ($percents%)" -PercentComplete:$percents
    }
  }
  $workbook.Close()
  $excel.Quit()
}

function FindFiles {

    param(
        [string]$filestore
    )

    $length = $filestore.Length
    $GuidArray = @()

    for($line=0;$line -le $filestore.Count;$line++){

            $check = $filestore[$line]
            echo $check
            $length2 = $check.Length


            $fileGuid = $check | ForEach-Object{$_.FileGuid}





            $GuidArray = $GuidArray + $fileGuid    
    }

    write-host "-------------------------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Yellow

    $filepath = Read-Host " Please Enter File Path to Search"

    for ($counter=0;$counter -lt $GuidArray.Count;$counter++){
        $fileArray = @()
        $guidcheck = $GuidArray[$counter]
        $file = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force $filePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $false) -and  ( $_.Name -like "*$guidcheck*") } | Select-Object Directory,Name| Format-Table -AutoSize 
        $fileArray += $file
    }

    Write-Output $fileArray





}

function CopyFiles {

    param(
        [string]$fileArray
    )

    for ($counter = 0;$counter -lt $fileArrray.Count;$counter++){
        echo $fileArray[$counter]
        #Copy-Item 
    }

}

function execute {
    $filestore = Import-Excel 'C:\594 Sample of Filestore.xlsx'
    echo $filestore
    $fileArray = @(FindFiles($fileArray))

    echo "test"
    echo $fileArray
    #CopyFiles($fileArray)
}
```

Comment: i do get the output test but all calls before and after are not producing anything

Comment: exit is a fairly evil thing to call from functions. throw also stops function execution, by the way, and won't kill the entire shell.

Comment: exit is only called in import-excel side to get the excel entered as an object but post that it doesnt work

Comment: i cannot provide you with a snippet of code as all the code related to each other. However if you want to see the code from the shell it is this. test

Comment: I believe you had commented on my earlier thread and I used that advice however the functions dont seem to be seeing any data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of `FindFiles` add this line:

```
Write-Output $GuidArray
```

This returns that variable to the standard output stream (the pipeline).

Similarily at the end of `FindFiles2` you need to do:

```
Write-Output $fileArray
```

Comment: trying it now will report back results

Comment: powershell ISE is very buggy

Comment: hmm still getting the same result with the write output inserted

Comment: Also are your functions in a module or just a .ps1 file? I just ask because making changes to modules require reloading via `import-module -force` or by doing `remove-module` first.

Comment: Good advice, but while PowerShell's [_success output stream_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection) is the _analog_ to _stdout_ in other shells, I wouldn't use the latter term in the context of discussing PowerShell.
It's also worth mentioning that `Write-Output` (and its alias, `echo`) is generally not necessary, and that things that produce output send that output to the success stream _by default_.

Comment: they are all in a ps1 file i am trying to see if putting the $filestore command  as a global variable will help. It appears to me that the two functions post filestore are getting no data which could be a result of the filestore itself not producing data.

Comment: it seems odd how difficult it is to just return values to other functions

Comment: interesting so putting the filestore as a global variable and then trying to call findfiles after the import was unsuccesfull. So for whatever reason $filesort is producing no data. However if you were to echo findfiles it produces data. very odd

Comment: Sounds like you need to fix why `Import-Excel` isn't working. I'd suggest using the Excel module from Doug Finke instead: https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel

Comment: appears to be working now . i will post the edited code